# How to make decimal to take up to two(2) values of series in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts4

How to make decimal to take up to two(2) values of series in amCharts?

I have tried in different ways with no appropriate response.

All the data is coming from API's so I need to change in series hover tips only like 12.04 instead of 12.041234532

Please help to sort this.

My series code as follows -

```
    let series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series1.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series1.dataFields.valueY = "total_energy_production_baht";
    // series1.dataFields.valueY = parseFloat("total_energy_production_baht").toFixed(2);
    //series1.dataFields.valueY = `${parseFloat('total_energy_production_baht').toFixed(2)}`;
    series1.strokeWidth = 2;
    // series1.tooltipText = "value: {valueY}, day change: {valueY.previousChange}";
    series1.tooltipText = string.total_price + ": {valueY} " + string.bath;
    //series1.tooltipText = "Total Price:"+ `parseFloat(${valueY}).toFixed(2)`+" Baht";
```

Comment: It would be great if you post sandbox as well. It's hard to tell from this

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript **toFixed** function to achieve this functionality.

```js
   var num = 5.56789;
   var n = num.toFixed(2);
   console.log('Here is the fixed decimal number=', n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`formatNumber`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-numbers/#Overriding_format) method on your `valueY` placeholder using the formats described [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-numbers/#Format_codes). To always force two decimals, use zeroes:

```
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY.formatNumber('#.00')}"
```